# "NameError: uninitialized constant Newsletter" in Heroku, but not in development, Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have an app on Heroku. I added a new model and a controller for "newsletter". In development, everything works fine. Then I ran these lines of code:

```
git commit -a -m "added newsletter"
git push origin master
git push heroku master
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

But after trying to get the index page, I got this message:

```
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
```

I ran `heroku run rails console` and typed in: `Newsletter.connection`

```
irb(main):001:0> Newsletter.connection
NameError: uninitialized constant Newsletter
        from (irb):1
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
        from /app/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0>
```

Then I ran `Heroku logs`:

```
2016-02-14T20:24:36.918613+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/newsletters" host=evening-basin-18662.herokuapp.com request_id=a7acad04-63e4-468f-9eac-bfec23c72773 fwd="87.245.109.31" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=404 bytes=1829
2016-02-14T20:24:36.919403+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/newsletters" for 87.245.109.31 at 2016-02-14 20:24:36 +0000
2016-02-14T20:24:36.924135+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-02-14T20:24:36.924138+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant NewslettersController):
```

Where did I go wrong? Thanks in advance!

Edit: models/newsletter.rb

```
class Newsletter < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

controllers/newsletters_controller.rb

```
class NewslettersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @newsletters = Newsletter.all
  end

  def new
    @newsletter = Newsletter.new
  end

  def create
    @newsletter = Newsletter.new(newsletter_params)
    if @newsletter.save
      # @user = User.find(current_user.id)
      #ExampleMailer.sample_email(@user).deliver
      redirect_to newsletters_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def newsletter_params
    params.require(:newsletter).permit(:name)
  end


end
```

config/routes.rb

```
resources :newsletters
```

Edit 2:

Solved by Frederich Cheung.

Frederick Cheung asked: "Did you definitely commit newsletter.rb?"

Then, I did this:

```
git add .
git commit -m "add newsletter"
git push origin master
git push heroku master
```

And after that, it worked.

Comment: Show us your `Newsletter` model

Comment: added model, routes and controller.

Comment: did update your gemfile.lock before pushing to heroku?

Comment: No, how do I do that?

Comment: Did you definitely commit newsletter.rb ?

Comment: Try to stop your server, and execute `spring stop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is due to an error in git handling, here a more verbose explanation to what Michael Cruz already pointed out:

For more info have a look at the [git commit documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)

**git commit
-a**   same as

**git commit
--all**

> Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified
>   and deleted, but **new files you have not told Git about are not
>   affected**.

For more info have a look at the [git add documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)

**git add**

> This command [git add] updates the index using the current content found in the
>   working tree, to prepare the content staged for the next commit. **It
>   typically adds the current content of existing paths as a whole**, but
>   with some options it can also be used to add content with only part of
>   the changes made to the working tree files applied, or remove paths
>   that do not exist in the working tree anymore.

**Is my file tracked?**

To find out if your file is tracked by git you can run `git status myFileName.rb`.
If it returns an error it is not tracked yet.

Answer (score 1):

Frederick Cheung asked: "Did you definitely commit newsletter.rb?"

Then, I did this:

```
git add .
git commit -m "add newsletter"
git push origin master
git push heroku master
```

And after that, it worked. (Weird, because I'm pretty sure, I ran git `commit -a -m "add newsletter"` )

Comment: `git commit -a` will not add new files, only those that have already been tracked. For new files, you need to run `git add`, as  you've now done.

Comment: Agree with @MichaelCruz. You should really use the two commands `git add .` then `git commit` to really commit everything.